# IIS 6 Wildcard Mappings

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-6

I need to install an MVC site to a bunch of servers running IIS 6 with a web setup installer. Is there a way I can build in a custom action to add the necessary wildcard mappings to the virtual directory programmatically? Perhaps a command line to run?

Comment: But what is @api in: C:\>cscript c:\inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs SET %G/Root/@api/ScriptMaps "*,%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0
.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,1,GET,HEAD,POST"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it myself:

http://forums.developer.mindtouch.com/archive/index.php/t-5863.html

Something like:

```
C:\>cscript c:\inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs SET %G/Root/@api/ScriptMaps "*,%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0
.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,1,GET,HEAD,POST"
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host, Version 5.6
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1996-2001. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.
```